# Trying to find a Harry Potter story

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I have been looking for a story that I read a couple of years ago. It’s about how Harry was bitten while running track or cross country. It was a none magic story. It is a Fenrir/Harry pairing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any idea where you might have read it?

Comment: This question is very sparse. You could greatly improve it by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Fenrir and his pack are running from do believe some kind of government hunters.

Comment: Fenrir/harry? Is it time for a frarry tag? Or henrir?